# MYSQL - Cannot create event scheduler

Tags: mysql

iam using MYSQL maria DB and run script

```
CREATE EVENT 'delete_expire_sku_permonth'
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2017-11-23 00:00:00'
DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tablestok WHERE system_update < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY
END
```

and have error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''delete_expire_sku_permonth'
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2017-11-23 00:00' at line 1
```

What the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of the single quotes you put in this line CREATE EVENT 'delete_expire_sku_permonth'. Please try running the same without the single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I am not careful, and i missing ')', is solved now